# What if we had a universe that contained only two particles held together by the strong force?

Tags: strong-force

What if we had a universe that contained only two particles held together by the strong force?

What would be the behavior of the particles if the strong force suddenly vanished?

Comment: So your first question is: *What if we had a Universe that contained only a meson?*

Comment: [Asymptotic Freedom: From Paradox to Paradigm - Frank Wilczek](http://web.mit.edu/physics/people/faculty/docs/wilczek_nobel_lecture.pdf)

Comment: @AndreiGeanta, Sure, if the behavior did not depend on the particles.

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is, in particular, be more specific as to what exactly you want to know about this situation: If the universe contained only two particles held together by the strong force, then it would contain only two particles held together by the strong force. If you turn the strong force off, you have two non-interacting particles. What more that's not just as obvious do you want to know?

Comment: I'm not sure that the first question is coherent since a bound state of two colored particles, e.g., $q\bar{q}$ isn't just two particles.  Moreover, if the strong interaction vanished, wouldn't colored particles vanish, i.e., wouldn't the quark and gluon fields necessarily not exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our Universe, as far as we know, the only elementary matter particles that interact via strong force are quarks. If you limit the number of particles to 2, then these particles are in fact a quark-antiquark pair.

In the high energy limit, quarks can be treated as free particles. Furthermore, the interaction between quarks is reduced as they get closer due to the [antiscreening effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_freedom#Screening_and_antiscreening).

> *What would be the behavior of the particles if the strong force suddenly vanished?*

They will become free as individual particles and they will interact via the other three fundamental forces depending on the type of quarks that we are talking about.

### Link

[Free quark searches](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/reviews/rpp2014-rev-free-quark-searches.pdf)